# Relaxing eyes: what happens if I accommodate past far point

Tags: computers, vision, eye-strain

I am working with displays a lot, which causes eyestrain and a little bit of "seasickness" sometimes. To relax the eyes, a common 20-20-20 rule says that one should watch past 20 feet for 20 seconds after every 20 minutes. But would it be even more efficient to relax the eyes by watching at a far point and then relax the eyes even further by letting the vision to become blur. Or is this "relaxing even further" false subjective sensation about maximal relaxation of the lenses, what actually could happen in the eyes? I am capable of making the distant objects blur by this way, and the close objects seem also to become blurred.

Comment: 20 feet (~6 m) is effectively infinity for our eyes, that's why that value is given. I don't know that by creating blur, that you are relaxing anything as such.

Comment: Yes, completely relaxing the eyes will very slightly blur your vision at any distance, near or far. That's normal, for example, when we are deep in thought and have a "far away look in our eyes".